# Boto script for creating weighted record in route53 throws error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-route53

I have written a script which creates a weighted record and associates with health check. But as i need to create two records with same name,the first one gets created and in the second one ot throws error:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://route53.amazonaws.com/doc/2013-04-01/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>InvalidChangeBatch</Code><Message>Tried to create resource record set [name='atest.test.xyz.com.', type='A', set-identifier='Weighted'] but it already exists</Message></Error><RequestId>efab9b1d-26f6-11e6-a5f3-bdb3e07c9a4a</RequestId></ErrorResponse>
```

the code snippet is :

```
changes = ResourceRecordSets(conn, zoneId)
change = changes.add_change('CREATE', '{{ isv_alias }}' + '.{{ deployment_type }}' + '.xyz.com', 'A',ttl=300,identifier='Weighted',weight=1,health_check=hc_id,alias_evaluate_target_health=1)
change.add_value('x.x.x.x')
result = changes.commit()
```

Comment: this doesn't look like boto3?  Not entirely sure of the syntax but I guess you need to add a "name" field to the add_change parameters.  "name1" and "name2" would probably work as values

Comment: Yes this boto script is called within from ansible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set identifier has to be unique.  Think of it like a friendly name for that IP address.